# Can every finite graph be represented by an arithmetic sequence of natural numbers?

Tags: graph-theory, nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-progression

*(This is a follow-up to my previous questions [Natural models of graphs?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11647/natural-models-of-graphs).)*

Erdös in [The Representation of a Graph by Set Intersections](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1966-21.pdf) (1966) states:

> **Theorem**. Let $G$ be an arbitrary
> graph. Then there is a set $S$ and a
> family of subsets $S_1, S_2, ...$ of
> $S$ which can be put into one-to-one
> correspondence with the vertices of
> $G$ in such a way that $x_i$ and $x_j$ are joined by an
> edge of $G$ iff $i \neq j$
> and $S_i \cap S_j \neq \emptyset$.

If we identify $S$ with a set of prime numbers and each $S_i$ with the product of its members we get the following:

> **Corollary**. Let $G$ be an arbitrary finite
> graph. Then there is a sequence of natural numbers $(n_1, n_2, ..., n_k)$
> which can be put into one-to-one
> correspondence with the vertices of
> $G$ in such a way that  $x_i$ and $x_j$ are joined by an edge iff $i \neq j$ and GCD$(n_i, n_j) > 1$.

We can choose the prime numbers (the elements of $S$, from which the $n_i$ are built) arbitrarily, and so the question arises, whether they can always be choosen in such a way, that the set $(n_1, n_2, ..., n_k)$ is an [arithmetic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Of course every *complete* graph on $k$ nodes can be represented by an arithmetic sequence: just take some consecutive sequence of even numbers. [Green-Tao's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) guarantees that also every *empty* graph on $k$ nodes can be represented by an arithmetic sequence $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_k)$ of primes.

> **Question:** Can every graph on $k$ nodes be represented by an arithmetic sequence
> of natural numbers such that  $n_i$ and $n_j$ are joined by an edge iff $n_i \neq n_j$ and GCD$(n_i, n_j) > 1$

This would be one kind of *natural model of a graph*, that I was looking for, originally.

Maybe some references?

**Added**: Due to Kevin's concise answer and Thomas' comment, I'd like to add the following question:

> **Question:** If not every graph on $k$ nodes can be represented by an arithmetic sequence
> of natural numbers such that  $n_i$ and $n_j$ are joined by an edge iff $n_i \neq n_j$ and GCD$(n_i, n_j) > 1$: **Are there interesting classes of graphs with this property?**

Comment: Umm...I think the Green-Tao theorem is overkill. To get n+1 coprime integers in an arithmetic progression just consider 1,1+d,1+2d,...,1+nd with d=n!. Nice question though.

Comment: Oh...wait...apart from the fact that it clearly can't be done.

Comment: I did feel that Green-Tao theorem is overkill, thanks for showing me why. I guess there will be an answer to your second comment?

Comment: The new question is not a real question, I feel.  Pick a class of graphs *you* think is interesting and try enough examples that you can make a reasonable guess that it works.

Comment: I will try. And I'll try this: to find other progressions (than arithmetic ones) for which the statement holds for all graphs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK so take the unique tree on 3 vertices. Claim: you can't encode this with an arithmetic progression (AP). For if the AP is $a,a+d,a+2d$ then (because we have two edges) either vertices 1 and 2 are joined, or vertices 2 and 3 are joined (or both). Hence there is some $p>1$ such that either $p$ divides both $a$ and $a+d$, or $p$ divides both $a+d$ and $a+2d$. In either case, $p$ then divides $d$, so it divides $a$, so it divides everything, so the graph is complete.

Comment: This argument can be extended to show the same for any tree (on at least three vertices). Might it still be possible for an interesting subclass of graphs? (e.g. graphs containing cycles, or graphs with complete components.)

Comment: What do you think: May I change my question to "Which finite graphs may be represented...?" 