# Almost or probably complete graph invariants?

Tags: graph-theory

Assuming that there are no known complete graph invariants in the spirit of [Harrsion's question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11631/complete-graph-invariants) that do not depend on any labelling (see [graph property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_invariant) at Wikipedia), I wonder if there are graph invariants that are

- almost complete, i.e. discriminating almost all finite graphs up to isomorphism
- almost complete in a weaker sense, i.e. discriminating all finite graphs except for a small, but finite fraction (the smaller the fraction the greater the invariant's discriminating power)
- probably complete, i.e. not proven to be incomplete yet (e.g. by counterexamples)

Can anyone provide examples or references?

Comment: A program that one of my friends used for graph isomorphism is "nauty" http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/ .  Not sure exactly what goes into it (nor have I used it personally) so I'm not writing this up as an answer, but there are references on that webpage.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand the question well enough to know whether this is a reasonable answer. But a standard observation concerning the graph isomorphism problem is that there is an approach that feels as though it almost works: work out the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix.

There is a small technical problem that you can't do this exactly, and a more fundamental problem that if you have eigenvalues of multiplicity greater than 1 then you don't distinguish all graphs. But I would guess that almost all graphs have adjacency matrices with distinct eigenvalues. Can anyone confirm this? And if that is the case, does it answer your question?

Comment: AFAIK it is still unsolved as to whether almost all graphs are distinguished by their spectrum; I think Willem Haemers has conjectured this, at least in conversation, and perhaps also in print.



Comment: Almost all graphs are not trees. But if two random trees are iso-spectral with positive probability then that is not so satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Though painfully slow to compute, I've yet to find a counterexample to the first invariant proposed in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503316) paper by Mehendale: a vector of integers counting, for each n, the number of labeled subgraphs of G which are trees on n vertices.

Update: I've since discovered several counterexamples, perhaps the simplest being

S3 U P2 U P2

and

P4 U P3 U P1

both of which yield the signature (8,5,3,1)

Comment: Sounds interesting, at least to find out when and why this invariant might eventually fail.