# Complete tree invariants?

Tags: graph-theory

If we take a graph invariant to be "a property that depends only on the abstract structure, not on graph representations such as particular labellings or drawings of the graph" (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_invariant)), I have the feeling that Harrsion's question for [complete graph invariants](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11631/complete-graph-invariants) remained basically unanswered, since [Greg's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11631/complete-graph-invariants/11715#11715) is mainly about (canonical) labellings.

Thinking - as Harrison did - of "the usual ones (the Tutte polynomial, the spectrum, whatever)", I'd like to repeat Harrison's question, but restrict it to trees:

> Are there any known complete tree invariants?

Comment: In case this may be of interested, a conjectural complete tree invariant is the chromatic symmetric function: http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/does_the_symmetric_chromatic_function_distinguish_trees

Comment: All trees on $n$ vertices have the same Tutte polynomial, so it's not that. Are you just asking for a canonical labelling?

Comment: @Emil: No, I am not asking for a canonical labelling, but for something more "structural", something expressible without any usage of labels.

Comment: @Steven: Can you - or someone else - tell me, what the "path sequence" is? (I didn't find a definition with Google.) Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

@Hans: The path sequence of $G$ is $(p_1, p_2, ...)$ where $p_i$ is the number of $i$-edge path subgraphs of $G$ isomorphic to an $i$-edge path.  For a tree, this is the same as the number of pairs of vertices at mutual distance $i$.  Morin, Wagner and I proved [arXiv:math/0609339] that the path and degree sequences of a tree (actually, something a but more general) can be determined from its chromatic symmetric function, but OTOH the path and degree sequences do not together determine the tree up to isomorphism; there is an 11-vertex counterexample in our article (due to Eisenstat and Gordon).