# What is graph canonisation?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

In a paper I am working on, I come across a term called  "graph canonisation "

According to [math-world Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CanonicalLabeling.html):

> A canonical labeling, also called a canonical form, of a graph $G$ is a graph $G^{'}$ which is isomorphic to $G$ and which represents the whole isomorphism class of $G$ (Piperno 2011). The complexity class of canonical labeling is not known

Could one elaborate on that ?

**Motivation** : I am working on graph isomorphism [(See this paper by E.M Luks)](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~luks/CanLabel.pdf).

Comment: Very relevant is (Greg Kuperberg's answer in) [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11631/complete-graph-invariants). Also note the Borel-reducability results of Friedman and Stanley.

Answer (score 2):

The wikipedia article seems to explain it pretty well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization